# How to present massive amounts of repeated data to user

Tags: php, mysql, api, select, nosql

Ok, so I'm using an API to aggregate a bunch of data - for the sake of an example, we'll say the data is about gardening groups. I eventually want to show all of this data on one page.

So to start out, I can search for a `gardener` and get back some information about the group he's in. For example, if I search for `Bob`, we'll get back that he's in a gardening group with `Lisa`, `Ted`, `Gary`, and `Jill`.

I can do further queries on each of these names to find out more about them. For example, I can do a `tools` query, a `fruits` query, a `vegetables` query.

An example of a `tools` query for Bob might return something like this:

```
tools: [
         {
           Id: 117,
           name: "Rake"
         },
         {
           Id: 175,
           name: "Shovel"
         },
         {
           Id: 55,
           name: "Hoe"
         },
         {
           Id: 270,
           name: "Wheelbarrow"
         }
      ]
```

and etc. for all the other queries. Basically, each query returns a minimal amount of information to identify the different `tools, fruits, vegetables` for each gardener.

What I'm wanting to do is to combine all of this data on one page. So, if someone searches for Bob, they get not only all the `tools, fruits, and vegetables` for him, they also get that information for everybody in his gardening group. This requires quite a few queries (done using curl to external API provider) to get all that info, which I want to now present to the user looking up `Bob`.

However, I also want to present more detailed data alongside the information from the API. For example, I have a `description` for each of the `tools, fruits, and vegetables` that I want to present to the user. So instead of something like this, which I could just use an API for:

```
User enters 'Bob'

My site returns:

The other members of Bob's gardening group are Lisa, Ted, Gary, and Jill.

Bob's stats:
Bob uses the following tools: a rake, shovel, hoe, and wheelbarrow.
Bob is growing the following fruits: strawberries and blueberries.
Bob is growing the following vegetables: carrots, radishes, and potatoes.

Lisa's stats:
Lisa uses the following tools: gardening gloves, a shovel, and a rake.
etc.
```

I want something like this, which includes a description (and more information, this is just an example of pulling in outside information and incorporating it with the API results). Currently the description data is stored in MySQL tables:

```
User enters 'Bob'

My site returns:

The other members of Bob's gardening group are Lisa, Ted, Gary, and Jill.

Bob's stats:
   Bob's tools:
     Rake - Used to loosen soil and remove weeds
     Shovel - Used to remove soil 
     Wheelbarrow - Used to transport large loads
     Hoe - Used to move small amounts of soil
   Bob's fruits:
     Blueberries - A small, sweet berry full of antioxidants.

   etc.

Lisa's stats:
   Lisa's tools:
      Rake - Used to loosen soil and remove weeds
      Shovel - Used to remove soil 
      Gardening gloves - Used to protect hands
   etc.
```

So herein lies the problem, when I get the results of the `tools`, `fruits`, and `vegetables`, there's going to be a lot of duplicate data. Gardeners are going to have many of the same tools and they're going to be planting many of the same types of fruits and vegetables.

What I'm doing now is aggregating all of the queried data, then pulling in the tables from MySQL for `tools`, `fruits`, and `vegetables`.

Something like `SELECT id, name, description FROM tools`. I then make an object out of the result set for easier access, in the form of

```
$toolsSQL = 

117 =>
     { 
       id: 117,
       name: "Rake",
       description: "Used to loosen soil and remove weeds"
     }
 55 =>
     etc.
```

e.g., if I'm currently adding in descriptions for Bob's tools, I can do `$toolsSQL[$toolID]['description']` to get at the description instead of `mysqli_query(sprintf("SELECT description FROM tools WHERE id = '%d';", $toolID));`

My problem with this approach is that it pulls in a lot of extraneous data, for example, there might be a tool by the name of `Mongolian gardening oscillator` in the MySQL table that is never needed. However, because there IS a lot of repetition, it's easier to call on `$toolsSQL[117]['description']` multiple times than do multiple mysqli queries of  `SELECT description FROM tools WHERE id = '117'` (I THINK - I am not 100% sure if what I'm saying is correct here, but it is my naive assumption that it is faster this way).

What I'm wanting to add on is way more than just a description. However, it's making me a bit uneasy that I'm using SQL queries to get the same data over and over and over, ESPECIALLY data that is always the same. It seems like there is probably a much faster way at getting at data which only ever needs to be accessed by `SELECT` statements, but I'm too much of a novice to know of any alternatives (or whether what I'm doing is acceptable or preferred). Is this something that would work well with a NoSQL solution? I'd appreciate any help, thanks and kudos to those of you who actually read through this huge example :P. I wish I knew more in order to ask a bit more directly ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the number of queries to the SQL Database, a good solution is to try group to group your multiple requests in one. An example :

```
/* I'm supposing that $gardeners looks like that : 
* {
*   bob : {
*     tools: [{Id: 117,name: "Rake"}, {Id: 175,name: "Shovel"},[...]],
*     fruits : [...]
*   },
*   Lisa : {tools: [...]}
* }
*/
$toolIDs = array();
foreach ($gardeners as $gardener) {
  foreach ($gardener->tools as $tool) {
    $toolIDs[] = $tool->Id; // get Ids of all used tools
  }
}
$toolIDs = array_unique($toolIDs); // remove duplicate Ids

// fetch the description of all the used tools in one go
$result = mysqli_query(sprintf("SELECT id, description FROM tools WHERE id IN ('%d');", implode("','", $toolID)));
```

Since we have a id-description couple, we can construct an array like the one you were talking about, but with only the used tools, and with only one request. By doing the same with fruits and vegetable, you can get all the necessary data (and only the necessary data) with a total of 3 sql requests.

If the data your are aggregating doesn't change often, you should also look into caching your results. That way, it would lower the usage of both the API and MySQL. Take a look at APC ou memcache for example.